# JLabel unicode when recieving data from a server

Tags: java, unicode, jframe, server

I'm trying to display french words recieved from a server in a JLabel, but all I get are messed up words(Guess not unicode or smth).

```
InetAddress addr;
Socket sock = new Socket("192.168.0.104", 81);
addr = sock.getInetAddress();
System.out.println("Csatlakoztam:" + addr);
DataOutputStream adat = new DataOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
adat.write('a');
adat.flush();
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
p = String.valueOf(input.readLine());
sock.close();
```

This is how I want to display the text :
`cp.add(new JLabel(connect()));`
All I get is : [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNTIb.jpg)

How could I solve this?

Comment: You need more information. What is `cp`? What is `connect()`? Do you mean `sock.connect()` by any chance?

Comment: CP is a container in my gui class, `cp = this.getContentPane();`
`connect()` is the function whose elements are shown in the original post, it returns the p variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to be using a differed `Charset` when creating your `InputStreamReader`. Try:

```
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream(), "charsetName"));
```

where `charsetName` is one of the charsets listed [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html).